# Client socket can't connect to server socket when sockaddr_in is passed to server object as a normal variable

Tags: c++

I'm using the constructor to create, bind and start listen  client socket as:

```
socket_server::socket_server(sockaddr_in serv_add){
    serv_status = 0;
    //bind socket to specific port
    if(bind(get_sockfd(),(sockaddr*)&serv_add,sizeof(serv_add))!= 0){
        cout<<"Socket bind failed..\n"<<endl;
        serv_status = 0;
    }else{
        cout<<"Socket successfully binded ....\n"<<endl;
        //start listening client
        if(listen(get_sockfd(),max_client) != 0){
            cout<<"Can not put server into ready state...\n"<<endl;
            serv_status =0;
        }else{
            cout<<"Server is ready to listen client...\n"<<endl;
            serv_status = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In main:

```
sockaddr_in serv_add;
    
    memset(&serv_add,0,sizeof(serv_add));// only use to reset value for variable
    serv_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_add.sin_port = htons(port); //port 6789
    serv_add.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    
    socket_server server(serv_add); //create, bind, listen are successfull
```

But client can't connect to server (socket server don't receive any signals from the client).
And I tried to bind server with sockaddr_in as a local inside class  instead of passing parameter as below:

```
socket_server::socket_server(){
    sockaddr_in serv_add;
    serv_status = 0;
    //assign value for serv_add
    memset(&serv_add,0,sizeof(serv_add));// only use to reset value for variable
    serv_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_add.sin_port = htons(port);//6789
    serv_add.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    
    if(bind(get_sockfd(),(sockaddr*)&serv_add,sizeof(serv_add))!= 0){
        cout<<"Socket bind failed..\n"<<endl;
        serv_status = 0;
    }else{
        cout<<"Socket successfully binded ....\n"<<endl;
        //start listen from client socket
        if(listen(get_sockfd(),max_client) != 0){
            cout<<"Can not put server into ready state...\n"<<endl;
            serv_status =0;
        }else{
            cout<<"Server is ready to listen client...\n"<<endl;
            serv_status = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In main: socket_server server; //all of the things are OK and the client has been connected to the server

I don't see the difference but I don't know why client can't connect to server in the first solution. I really appreciated if someone can let me know why?

Comment: There are too many unknowns. Does `get_sockfd()` return a new descriptor every time or what? You'd better make a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comment. socket_server is an inheritance class from the base class socket_class. One server object is created, it will call to constructor of base to create sockfd as socket_class::socket_class(){
 sockfd = -1;
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(sockfd == -1){
  cout<<"Can not create a socket..\n"<<endl;
 }else{
  cout<<"Socket has been created..\n"<<endl;
 }
}

Comment: I didn't ask about `socket_server` though. Please make a [mcve].